# unable to store data from file into array in matlab

Tags: matlab

i am trying to fetch integer value stored in result_cluster.txt
and trying to store into an array

```
aiclu(i,1)=a;
```

but I'm not getting the desired result. Instead a value of `0` is stored in the array.   Here's my code:

```
fid20=fopen('result_cluster.txt','r');
i=1;
k=1;
aclu_end=zeros(11,1);
aiclu=zeros(962,1);

while(~feof(fid20))

   a=fscanf(fid20,'%d',1);
   disp(a); 
   disp(i);

   aiclu(i,1)=a; 
   i=i+1;

   disp(aiclu(i,1));
   if a==32
     aclu_end(k,1)=i;

     disp('hello');
     disp(aclu_end(k,1));
     k=k+1;
   end    
end
fclose(fid20);
```

result_cluster.txt

```
2
3
4
34
56

81
85 
89

102
109
110 
...
```

I get this output:

```
disp(a) = 2
disp(i) = 1
```

For `aiclu(i,1)=a;` I get this error:  `"??? Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch."`

Comment: Are you sure that `a` is a single value and not a vector? `a` being a vector would cause that error.

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is in line 14 of your code above. You increment `i` - and **then** display it. So while you store the value of `a` in `aiclu(i,1)`, you are actually displaying `aiclu(i+1,1)`.
Your code runs fine when I try it and your error doesn't occur until the end of the file - so the condition for your `while`-loop is inadequate.

**Edit**

If you run your code in the Matlab debugger, you'll notice that the last value for `a` is an empty vector:

```
a = []
```

This cannot be assigned to `aiclu`.

Comment: @tabish : Please consider accepting this answer by clicking the checkmark (✓) next to the voting buttons or comment on what doesn't work for you.